# Make duplicate rows but change specific characters to lowercase in duplicates - R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+------------+
|site        |
+------------+
|JPN Tokyo   |
|AUS Sydney  |
|CHN Beijing |
```

But I'd like to make duplicate rows of the existing rows but with the 2nd and 3rd character changed to lowercase such that the dataframe becomes like this:

```
+------------+
|site        |
+------------+
|JPN Tokyo   |
|Jpn Tokyo   |
|AUS Sydney  |
|Aus Sydney  |
|CHN Beijing |
|Chn Beijing |
```

Would anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We expand the rows with `uncount`, then create a logical condition with `duplicated` on the 'site', replace the substring values to lower case using `sub` within `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   uncount(2) %>%   
   mutate(site = case_when(duplicated(site)
    ~ sub("^(.)(\\w+)", "\\1\\L\\2", site, perl = TRUE),
        TRUE ~ site))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  site       
  <chr>      
1 JPN Tokyo  
2 Jpn Tokyo  
3 AUS Sydney 
4 Aus Sydney 
5 CHN Beijing
6 Chn Beijing
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(site = c("JPN Tokyo", "AUS Sydney", "CHN Beijing"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

edit:  @AnilGoyal suggested the use of map_dfr, that reduced the call to only one line.

```r
library(tidyverse)    

data <- 
    tribble(
        ~site,      
        
        'JPN Tokyo',   
        'AUS Sydney', 
        'CHN Beijing' )

#option1
map_dfr(data$site, ~list(sites = c(.x, str_to_title(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   sites      
#>   <chr>      
#> 1 JPN Tokyo  
#> 2 Jpn Tokyo  
#> 3 AUS Sydney 
#> 4 Aus Sydney 
#> 5 CHN Beijing
#> 6 Chn Beijing

#option2
map(data$site, ~rbind(.x, str_to_title(.x))) %>%
    reduce(rbind) %>%
    tibble(site = .)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   site[,1]   
#>   <chr>      
#> 1 JPN Tokyo  
#> 2 Jpn Tokyo  
#> 3 AUS Sydney 
#> 4 Aus Sydney 
#> 5 CHN Beijing
#> 6 Chn Beijing
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Good one. Using map_dfr will eliminate need of last two steps

Comment: @AnilGoyal and is also much faster!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` to replace characters at specific position.

```
df1 <- df
substr(df1$site, 2, 3) <- tolower(substr(df1$site, 2, 3))
df1

#         site
#1   Jpn Tokyo
#2  Aus Sydney
#3 Chn Beijing

res <- rbind(df1, df)
res[order(res$site), , drop = FALSE]

#         site
#2  Aus Sydney
#5  AUS Sydney
#3 Chn Beijing
#6 CHN Beijing
#1   Jpn Tokyo
#4   JPN Tokyo
```